# Is there any good way to implement nested form in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been trying to find a decent solution for nested form, but I couldn't find any tutorial or blog on this topic. Please come and rescue.

Comment: I came and rescued. But you never accepted my answer...

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you'll want to check our Ryan's screencast:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Once you've seen the tutorial, you'll want to play around with the nested_form_for gem:
https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

If you need to see it in action, I've done a working carrierwave+nested form example here:
https://github.com/galaxylord/carrierwave_nested

You can always poke around the rails guides as well for some examples:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Hope this puts you on the right track!

Comment: Thanks so much, Galaxy!  This is really helpful for us newbies trying to make this work!